# Wi-Fi tethering with HTC Magic

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, htc-magic

Will Wi-Fi tethering work in HTC Magic running Android 2.2?

I wonder also, is the 2.2 update for htc magic a official update or one of these custom ROMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do Wi-Fi tethering with the HTC Magic.  However, [it *might* require a custom ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=966583).

All versions of the HTC Magic except for the Dream/G1 have gotten an official 2.2 update, as far as I am aware.  This includes the T-Mobile myTouch 3G and the Vodafone Magic.

Comment: Not all versions. I have a Google Ion phone (htc magic 32B) whose only available versions were Android 1.5 and 1.6 I think I will never buy again a "developer phone".