# Wifi tethering unavailable HTC Magic

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tethering, wifi-hotspot, htc-magic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wifi tethering with HTC Magic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/wifi-tethering-with-htc-magic)

Hi,

Got a HTC Magic (the black one) with official froyo 2.2.1 in it, but when I went to check there is no WiFi tethering available in the menu (although, there is usb tethering).

Is there any way I could put this old phone to work as a portable hotspot? I mean, are there any apps I could download to enable the wifi tether?

I'd just prefer not to have it rooted, custom ROM, if possible...

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only tinkered with it a little, but I'm pretty sure that you can only create a WiFi tether with an Android 2.2.x device if the manufacturer allows for it or if you root your phone and install something like Barnacle.

I found [this thread](http://androidforums.com/htc-magic/5994-tethering-htc-magic-bluetooth-canada.html) over at Android Forums in which the first reply specifies that the Magic doesn't support WiFi tether.

If you can handle having a USB cable connected between your laptop and phone PdaNet seems to work well for people without root.

Comment: I agree, you probably have to be rooted to do this via WiFi.

Comment: Meh.. I was afraid of that... but seems to be the case. That would be so cool though if such a cheap phone could make it all -_-

Comment: You should look into rooting your phone.  So long as you're careful and make sure you understand the whole process before you begin it really isn't that scary.  I would double-check that unrooting is at least as easy as rooting for your particular device as well in case you ever need to send it in for warranty reasons, but rooting affords you a lot of additional flexibility with your device.  And don't forget: step one is always _make a backup!_